# sudo: unable to resolve host debian: Name or service not known. I've already set host name in /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts but it keeps changing?

Tags: debian, hostname, hosts, vps

Hello Linux community.
I have a VPS service bought from Vultr, so this is not some home standalone PC with Linux installed on it.  I have to deal with all this obscure Control Panel setup they "provide".
The problem began after I've reinstalled operating system on this VPS instance I pay for.
I've changed `kali-linux` (that was also my hostname back then) to `debian 11`.  I havent't destroyed this vps instance. I just reinstalled the OS. I have the same IP as before.

After I've changed the operating system to `debian 11`, I also wanted to change the host name to `debian` and it was the beginning of my problems.

After system was reinstalled I noticed, that there is a special button in Vultr's Customer Panel, 2 change the hostname, so I did press it, system reinstalled one more time very fast and I hoped for the best.

[image]

When I'm logged in VPS and check `/etc/hostname` it claims, it's `debian`.

```
rafal@debian:~$ cat /etc/hostname
debian
```

When I check `/etc/hosts` it looks like this:

```
rafal@debian:~$ cat /etc/hosts
# Your system has configured 'manage_etc_hosts' as True.
# As a result, if you wish for changes to this file to persist
# then you will need to either
# a.) make changes to the master file in /etc/cloud/templates/hosts.debian.tmpl
# b.) change or remove the value of 'manage_etc_hosts' in
#     /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg or cloud-config from user-data
#
127.0.1.1 kali_linux.edu kali_linux
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I don't have any qualified domain name, so I have no idea what to put after `127.0.1.1`, but I'm sure as hell, I don't want `kali_linux.edu`.

In the same line, at the very end of it, I need to change `kali_linux` into `debian`. But when I've changed it once, it reverts into old values, after vps restart.

I can see, that there are some commented lines referring to this file: `/etc/cloud/templates/hosts.debian.tmpl`, but when I try to edit it (using Vim), I get this:

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name "/etc/cloud/templates/.hosts.debian.tmpl.swp"
          owned by: root   dated: Wed Jan 04 19:48:16 2023
         file name: /etc/cloud/templates/hosts.debian.tmpl
          modified: YES
         user name: root   host name: debian
        process ID: 1272
While opening file "/etc/cloud/templates/hosts.debian.tmpl"
             dated: Fri Dec 16 16:50:25 2011

(1) Another program may be editing the same file.  If this is the case,
    be careful not to end up with two different instances of the same
    file when making changes.  Quit, or continue with caution.
(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
    If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r /etc/cloud/templates/hosts.debian.tmpl"
    to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
    If you did this already, delete the swap file "/etc/cloud/templates/.hosts.debian.tmpl.swp"
    to avoid this message.
```

And I understand nothing from this.
All I know, a swap file is a file used to dump some portion of RAM memory, when the physical RAM is full. I have no idea what is a swap file for some other file  :-(

But this file `/etc/cloud/templates/hosts.debian.tmpl` looks like this:

```
## template:jinja
{#
This file (/etc/cloud/templates/hosts.debian.tmpl) is only utilized
if enabled in cloud-config.  Specifically, in order to enable it
you need to add the following to config:
   manage_etc_hosts: True
-#}
# Your system has configured 'manage_etc_hosts' as True.
# As a result, if you wish for changes to this file to persist
# then you will need to either
# a.) make changes to the master file in /etc/cloud/templates/hosts.debian.tmpl
# b.) change or remove the value of 'manage_etc_hosts' in
#     /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg or cloud-config from user-data
#
{# The value '{{hostname}}' will be replaced with the local-hostname -#}
127.0.1.1 {{fqdn}} {{hostname}}
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

The effect of all this confusion is, that I have this error `sudo: unable to resolve host debian: Name or service not known.`

```
rafal@debian:~$ sudo apt install unattended-upgrades
sudo: unable to resolve host debian: Name or service not known
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
unattended-upgrades is already the newest version (2.8).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 libappstream4 libdw1 libglib2.0-bin libgstreamer1.0-0 libpackagekit-glib2-18 libstemmer0d libunwind8 packagekit
  packagekit-tools python3-software-properties software-properties-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

## How to permanently change hostname to `debian`?

Comment: Ask your provider to fix it, you're paying them for that. They know where those template variables are filled and can check why there's a mismatch between your hostname in the panel and the current value.